# cross- browser issues.how to handle in code level

Tags: cross-browser

i have an issue in my css where on saafari alone min-width is not accepting but chrome is accepting min-width. how to handle this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.